# How I can resolve this?

Tags: javascript, utm

I need help with this for resolve it, is simple but i don´t find the solution

```html
 <script>
    $("#test").click(function(){
          var sld = my_sld();
          var tld = my_tld();
          var domain = sld+tld;
          window.location.href="http://example.com/check?domain="+test;
     })
    </script>

    <button id=“test” value=“Click">
```

Comment: Is `button#test` loaded before your `script`?

Comment: Exactly, you can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please remember to take the [tour] and read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) because right now you haven't _actually_ written a question. Please update your title to summarise the actual problem, and in your question explain (1) what you are trying to do, (2) what you wrote to do that, (3) what it does instead, and (4) what your own analysis is about why things might be wrong and where you got stuck trying to fix this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your`script` is  load before document or specific `button` load:
please place `script` after `button` or use `$(document).ready()`  event.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
   
   $("#test").click(function(){
        //  var sld = my_sld();
       //   var tld = my_tld();
       //   var domain = sld+tld;
          window.location.href="http://example.com/check?domain="+test;
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<input type="button" id="test" value="Click" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what doesn't work is the following:
When loading the page comes with the utm already defined, for example: http://example.com/?utm_source=Google.

The link button will be different, but I need to click on the utm_source and go to: http://myweb.com/?utm_source=Google

Missing only that detail, apologies and thank you very much @FrustratedDeveloper